# How can i create a TextView right beside an ImageView in xml

Tags: android, xml

How can i create a `TextView` that is right beside an image view in xml, i keep trying and end up getting a messed up layout.

The text is meant to describe what the image is about to it has to be right be side and aligned, any pointers or help would be appreciated

[What I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDz6H.png)

My xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.drecot.chopperattack.HelpActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/splash">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpscreen"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton"
            android:src="@drawable/fuelbig" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:text="you can turn away now if you wish"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpscreen"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton"
            android:src="@drawable/fuelsmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:text="you can turn away now if you wish"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add weight to your layout which automatically divides your layout according to proportion which you give, and remove all other 
paddings, margin_left, margin_right
etc. other stuff

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:src="@drawable/guitar"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:text="you can turn away now if you wish"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/guitar"
            android:layout_weight=".2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:text="you can turn away now if you wish"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/guitar"
            android:layout_weight=".2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:text="you can turn away now if you wish"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how do i  center gravity the image view?

Comment: I'm not getting your point exactly!! my code is already aligning the image of image view in center if your icon is fine then, please clear the exact scenario? you can add padding in image view like: android:padding="10dp" , it will shrink your icon towards center

Comment: on larger devices the text and image both align to the left of the screen

Comment: for that you should check your image whether it is multiple size depending on devices , like drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and so on  . or add padding left in your multiple dimension file

Comment: its not multiple size

Comment: so make it multiple from icon generator or photoshop so that it can align properly.

Comment: is it possible to have a scrollview inside a relative ayout

Comment: yeah you can add scroll view as..  you can surround both the Linear Layouts with a relative layout..  and then add scroll view around relative layout with height and width as match parent

Answer (score 1):

try this you can use `android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` like this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="test"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

**or use relative layout  like this**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `android:layout_toRightOf` for your textview. So your code for one imageview with oneTextview will be

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fuelbig" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:text="you can turn away now if you wish"
    android:textColor="#eee"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I removed `android:layout_below="@+id/helpscreen"` from your 1st imageview here because i dont think even that is necessary as it is your first view and not below anything

Comment: how do i center this?, tho the image and text views are not perfectly aligned

Comment: remove android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2" from textview

Answer (score 0):

See the follow code may be it help you out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.drecot.chopperattack.HelpActivity"
        >



      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              >
              <ImageView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                  />
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:text="this is for testing"
                  />

          </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              >
              <ImageView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                  />
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:text="this is for testing"
                  />

          </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```